# How to modify color channels individually in Halide?

Tags: c++, halide

I am interested in modifying individual color channels of Halide pixels. For example, how could I brighten the red channel but keep the green and blue channels unchanged? Brightening all colors for all pixels would look like this:

```
Halide::Expr value = input(x, y, c);
value = value * 2.0f;
brighter(x, y, c) = value;
```

But when attempting to brighten a single channel with the method below, an error is received.

```
Halide::Expr value = input(x, y, c);
value(x,y,0) = value(x,y,0) * 2.0f; // brighten red
value(x,y,1) = value(x,y,2);        // keep green the same
value(x,y,2) = value(x,y,3);        // keep blue the same
brighter(x, y, c) = value;
```

The error:

```
ImgPipe_Halide.cpp:88:14: error: no match for call to ‘(Halide::Expr) (Halide::Var&, Halide::Var&, int)’
```

So, how can I read individual channel values from pixels, and how can I modify them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use halide's select function

Example:

```
value = Halide::select(c == 0, input(x,y,c) * 2.0f,
                       input(x,y,c));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This works when applied to the input as you show. Interestingly this doesn't work when selecting from value (same error actually). I guess this means that the select function works with Halide functions and images but not with expressions.

Comment: This is the right solution. The error is because you can't index an Expr like that using free variables. You can only index Funcs with free variables. value(x, y, 0) is not meaningful - value is already input(x, y, c), not input(x, y, 0).